# How to get text from html and javascript tags and functions

Tags: javascript, php

Hello every one i want to get text from this code

```
$content = '<span class="version_host">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      document.writeln('streamin.to');
   </script>
</span>';
```

I want to get the text between `('streamin.to')` **streamin.to**

I am using **strip_tags()** function of php

```
$test = strip_tags($content);
echo $test;
```

**output:**

```
document.writeln('streamin.to');
```

please help me i want the text streamin.to only.

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to Use str_replace

```
<?php

$content = "<span class='version_host'>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.writeln('streamin.to');
   </script></span>";
$test = strip_tags($content);
$test1 = str_replace("');","",str_replace("document.writeln('","",$test));
echo $test1;

?>
```

OR USING preg_match

```
<?php
  $content = "<span class='version_host'>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
          document.writeln('streamin.to');
       </script></span>";
    $test = strip_tags($content);
$data = preg_match("/\'([^\']*?)\'/", $test, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Or Using explode as stated by @Rene Pot

```
<?php
 $content = "<span class='version_host'>
           <script type='text/javascript'>
              document.writeln('streamin.to');
           </script></span>";
$test = strip_tags($content);
$array = explode("'",$test);
$string = $array[1];
echo $string;
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: You're solution seems good to me, I don't know why someone downvoted it.  I'll upvote to compensate ;)

Answer (score 0):

What `strip_tags()` does is getting rid of any `<>` tags in a String, so `document.writeln('streamin.to');` remains.

Now, you only want to get the part between the single quotes, so best would be to use regular expressions (learn more on [regExOne.com](http://regexone.com))

```
output = "document.writeln('streamin.to');".match(/'([^']+)'/);
```

Then `output[1]` will contain what you're looking for.

**edit:**
If you want to achieve the same using php, try

```
preg_match("/'([^']+)'/", "document.writeln('streamin.to');", $output);
```

In that case `$output[1]` will contain what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

The following should provide what you need.

```
$content = "<span class='version_host'>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.writeln('streamin.to');
   </script>
</span>";
$test = strip_tags($content);
$array = explode("'", $test);
echo $array[1];
```

With `explode` you split the string `"document.writeln('streamin.to')"` by `'` delimiter, and get an array of 3 elements.